# android - select multiple images from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I'm using this code to select multiple images from gallery:

```
  private void openGallery() {

    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This code is working at most of devices but some phones can select only 1 image from gallery not multiple images(for example **Samsung A7** can select only 1 image). So how can I fix this?

Comment: That depends on the used File Manager or Gallery app. Install other apps.

Comment: You'll have to create your own custom gallery for that in a `GridView` like many social media apps do.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I think that will be so hard for me :(

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I fix this?

You can't, because there is nothing to fix.

`Intent` extras are requests. They are not commands. With `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)`, you are requesting that the user be allowed to select multiple images. There is no requirement that the implementation of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` must honor that request.